# Intellij doesnt break line in spring controller

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

When I press CTRL + ALT + L then every line gets breaked, except of a Controller line with annotations.

I set it up to wrap at 200 and it does so, just not on this as example:
[image]
I tried to set up the Code Style -> Java -> Wrapping and Braces.

Answer (score 1):

As written in [Oracle's Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/)

> Annotations, a form of metadata, provide data about a program that is
> not part of the program itself. Annotations have no direct effect on
> the operation of the code they annotate.
>
> Annotations have a number of uses, among them:
>
> 1. Information for the compiler — Annotations can be used by the
>    compiler to detect errors or suppress warnings.
> 2. Compile-time and
>    deployment-time processing — Software tools can process annotation
>    information to generate code, XML files, and so forth.
> 3. Runtime processing — Some annotations are available to be examined at
>    runtime.

They're not really directly executable and therefore not debuggable; for example what would you expect when putting a break point on `@Override` annotation?